# client_id is always null in ValidateClientAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I'm trying to validate client id in ValidateClientAuthentication function. I'm using grant_type=password flow. Here is how I'm passing client_id in auth token request body.

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=password&username=user1@test.com&password=pwduser1&client_id=B36B-07DEAC802BEA
```

When I try to access ClientId for validating client id, it is always null.

```
if (context.ClientId != null) 
   {
       //Set the client who initiated request is valid
       context.Validated();
   }
   else
   {
      //reject access to application
      context.Rejected();
      context.SetError("Invalid client_id", "Client_id must present in the request header");
   }
```

What is the right way to pass client id to token endpoint when grant_type=password?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if your `client_id` is passed as a form param, you'll have to get it by doing `context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);`

if your `client_id` is passed as an `Authorization` header, you can get it by doing `context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);`

once you've got the `client_id` from your request, do `context.Validated(clientId)`, this will set your `context.ClientId` property, this property will always be null until you've done `context.Validated()`

Comment: What if we are trying to implement two flows: Password and ClientCredentials. For password we aren't requiring ClientID because it's solely for the web app with actual users. ClientCredentials is intended to be used by third-parties for an API.

Comment: Man thank you so much for this - hard to find actual details about .net framework owin